# jQuery href tag

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, href, selector

I'm trying to use a jQuery selector for the clicking the following link but it's not working out. Anyone have an answer? Thanks.

```
$tweet.html(tweet.created_at + ' <a href="#" class="'+tweet.user+'">@' + tweet.user + '</a>: ' + tweet.message);
$tweet.appendTo($body);
$("a[href*=#]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('works');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your selector... href value should contain `'#'`, not `#`

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EricLease/23wga4z9/)

Comment: You have to provide more details or expand on "...it still doesn't work for some reason".  Have you debugged it?  What is $("a[href*='#']").length before the click evt is bound?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[href*='#']", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('works');
});
```